# Resolution constraints to getUserMedia() not working properly (WebRTC)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, constraints, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm new to WebRTC and testing a simple application for video streaming in Chrome. I have three different types of constraints with the following resolutions:

**qvga: 320 x 240,
vga: 640 x 480,
hdVga: 1280 x 720.**

When I capture media it runs fine. But when I start with the `qvga` resolution and click on any other button, it loads the object fine and I can even observe the constraints with `console.log`. The other two resolution settings i.e `vga` and `hdVga` it doesn't reflect any changes in window. Similarly when I reload the page and start with `hdVga` button it reflects `vga` resolution on screen whereas object property displays the constraints of `hdVga` and I'm unable to figure out the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>-->

</head>
<body>
    <video id="localVideo" controls poster="images/posterImage.png" ></video>
        <div id="buttons">
<button id="qvga">320x240</button>
<button id="vga">640x480</button>
<button id="hd">1280x720</button>
</div>
    <video id="remoteVideo" poster="images/posterImage.png" ></video>

    </script src="videoplayer.js"></script>
    <script src="adapter.js"></script>
    <script>
        var qVga = document.querySelector("button#qvga");
        var vga = document.querySelector("button#vga");
        var hdVga = document.querySelector("button#hd");
        var qVgaConstraints = {video:{
            mandatory:{
                maxWidth: 320,
                maxHeight: 240
            }
        },audio:true};

        var vgaConstraints = {video:{
            mandatory:{
                maxWidth: 640,
                maxHeight: 480
            }
        },audio:true}

        var hdVgaConstaints = {video:{
            mandatory:{
                maxWidth: 1280,
                maxHeight:720

            }
        },audio:true};

        function successCallback(stream){
            window.stream = stream;
            var video = document.querySelector("#localVideo");
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }
        function errorCallback(error){
        console.log("error: ",error);
        }
        qVga.onclick = function(){getMedia(qVgaConstraints)};
        vga.onclick = function(){getMedia(vgaConstraints)};
        hdVga.onclick = function(){getMedia(hdVgaConstaints)};
        function getMedia(constraints){
        console.log(constraints.video.mandatory);
        getUserMedia(constraints,successCallback,errorCallback);
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What is your browser? Firefox does not really support constraints like this to the extent that Chrome does. Also, webrtc is restricted by what the camera drivers will allow on that particular operating system.

Comment: I will go with benjamin here: constraints are just "hint", so whatever you ask, GUM will return what the camera can do that is "closer" to what you requested. the definition of "closer" is not clear yet (even among the standard committee members).

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I'm using chrome on win 8.1. I have to submit the project any still messing up with it. Any suggestions what to do in particular situation?

Comment: submit a bug to chrome for your particular camera, OS, chrome version

Comment: Firefox *does* support constraints, just not the non-standard ones Chrome is using. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282385/webrtc-firefox-constraints/28911694#28911694).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify both min and max values. Constraints inform the browser what range of values you are willing to work with. By not specifying a lower bound, you're agreeing to any resolution between 0x0 and 1280x768 in the hdVga case. Since Chrome defaults to 640x480, that's what you'll get.

To get 1280x768, specify a **min** value of 1280x768.

Constraints are not "hints" when used correctly, and ***will fail*** if you require values the camera cannot meet, so be careful about over-constraining, as people have different cameras with varying abilities. The camera is also a single resource, so you may have to share it with other tabs for instance. That's why constraints are built this way.

Using constraints, it is possible to specify that you prefer higher resolutions *without* forgoing lower-resolution cameras when that's all a user has, but I hesitate to elaborate further since Chrome uses an *outdated* constraints syntax that deviates quite a bit from the standard, and the standard addresses this more elegantly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282385/webrtc-firefox-constraints/28911694#28911694) for more.

The specification has finally stabilized, and an upcoming version of *adapter.js* (the cross-browser polyfill) should address this real soon. Until then, see [here](http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/resolution/) for a working example of Chrome's constraints, with the caveat that they wont work on other browsers.